# want to access User Friendly URLs on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

I am working on project which needs User Friendly URLs to access another page.
I tried many solution and many tips. "**`How to set .htaccess on  localhost`**".

My rewrite module is uncommented and AllowOverride is ALL.

when i am try to access any page then it give me "404 Not Found" error.

I saved my .htaccess file in webdirectory. Is it ok with there or place it other place.

For example: 
My original URL is `"**localhost/login.php?id=2**"`

i want this:
"**`localhost/login?id=2`**"

Any know about this?

Comment: I can't understand, have you wrote any rules for redirection, or you have only enabled htaccess and mod_rewrite?

Comment: Can you post you .htaccess file?

Comment: i set my .htaccess file. and its works on my online website. but i am just asking that its not working on localhost is there i save .htaccess file to another dictory or another format.